# ejecutar libreoffice desde php

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, ec2

Estoy haciendo un script en php para convertir archivos PPT a PDF. Tengo mi instancia ubuntu funcionando en Amazon Ec2. El problema es que cuando ejecuto desde la consola:

```
libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf prueba.ppt
```

Funciona bien pero cuando hago desde php:

```
exec('libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf prueba.ppt');
```

No funciona, no da error, ni crea el archivo. Alguien me puede ayudar con lo que este haciendo mal?. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Primero debes saber cual es el error que estás teniendo, para ello puedes intentar primero obtener la salida de la ejecución que estás lanzando:

```
Exec (" /usr/bin/soffice  --headless --convert-to pdf  prueba.docx  >> out.txt  2>&1 ");
```

Abres entonces out.txt para analiazarlo. En muchos casos se obtiene el sigiente error:

```
[Java framework] Error in function createSettingsDocument (elements.cxx).
javaldx failed!
Warning: failed to read path from javaldx
```

Si este es el caso debes setear previamente una carpeta home de trabajo para el libreoffice

```
Exec (" export export HOME=/RutaAMisScripts/Temp/ && /usr/bin/soffice  --headless --convert-to pdf  prueba.docx  >> out.txt  2>&1 ");
```